# Save result of select statement into wide table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have read about the possibilty to create wide tables (30,000 columns) in SQL server ([1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986.aspx))

**But how do I actually save the result of a select statement (one that has 1024+ columns) into a wide table?**

Because if I do:

```
Select * 
Into wide_table
From (
       **Select statement with 1024+ columns**
      ) b
```

I get: CREATE TABLE failed because column 'c157' in table 'wide_table' exceeds the maximum of 1024 columns.

**And, will I be able to query that table and all it's columns in a regular manner?**

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are right you are [allowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server) to created table with 30 000 columns, but you can `SELECT` or `INSERT` 'only' 4096 column in one clause:

[image]

So, in case of `SELECT` you will need to get the columns in parts or concatenate the results. All of this does not seem to be practical and easier and performance efficient.

If you are going to have so many columns, maybe it will be better to try to `UNPIVOT` the data and normalized it further.

Comment: I dont have a problem with creating the select statement (assume its bigger than 1024 and smaller than 4096)